# Error 403: "Flux query service disabled." But flux-enabled=true has been set in influxdb.conf

Tags: influxdb, fluxlang

I have been using InfluxDB (server version 1.7.5)  with the InfluxQL language for some time now. Unfortunately, InfluxQL does not allow me to perform any form of joins, so I need to use InfluxDB's new scripting language Flux instead.
The manual states that I have to enable Flux in `/etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf` by setting `flux-enabled=true` which I have done.  I restarted the server to make sure I got the new settings and started the Influx Command Line tool with "-type=flux". 
I then do get a different user interface than when I use InfluxQL. So far so good. I can also set and read variables etc. So I can set:

```
> dummy = 1
> dummy
1
```

However, when I try to do any form of query of the tables such as: `from(bucket:"db_OxyFlux-test/autogen")`
I always get

```
Error: Flux query service disabled. Verify flux-enabled=true in the [http] section of the InfluxDB config.
: 403 Forbidden
```

I found the manual for Fluxlang rather lacking in basic details of Schema exploration and so I am not sure if this is just an issue with my query raising this error or if something else is going wrong. I tested this both on my own home machine and on our remote work server and I get the same results.

Re: Vilix
Thank you. This lead me in the right direction. 
I realised that InfluxDB does not automatically read the config file (which is not very intuitive). But your solution also forces me to start the deamon by hand each time. After some more googling I used:
"sudo influxd config -config /etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf"
So hopefully now the daemon will start automatically each time on startup rather than me having to do this by hand.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and solution is to start `influxd` with `-config` option:

```
influxd -config /etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf
```

Comment: I am facing same issue. I tried with -config options but still getting 403 forbidden in api response with message "Flux query service disabled. Verify flux-enabled=true in the [http] section of the InfluxDB config."